# Cannot build BIRT-4.11.0

Tags: maven, build, birt

I pulled BIRT source branch 4.11.0 (https://github.com/eclipse/birt) and as mentioned triggered build using maven (mvn package -DskipTests) which failed because it could not resolve dependencies.

After analyzing found that Tycho maven plugin could not resolve dependencies mentioned in org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite/pom.xml (\build\org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite). As mentioned in Tycho wiki http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting checked that all the mentioned p2 repositories are available.

BIRT documentation didn't help as it is out-dated.

Here are what I use:

- JDK 1.8
- Maven 3.6.1

Stacktrace -

```
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.birt:org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite:4.11.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\dev\git\birt\build\org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite\pom.xml
[DEBUG] Using default execution environment 'JavaSE-1.7'
[DEBUG] Registered artifact repository org.eclipse.tycho.repository.registry.facade.RepositoryBlackboardKey(uri=file:/resolution-context-artifacts@C%253A%255Cdev%255Cgit%255Cbirt%255Cbuild%255Corg.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite)
[DEBUG] Added 0 locally built units to the target platform
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.birt:org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite:4.11.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\dev\git\birt\build\org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite\pom.xml
[DEBUG] No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.birt.axis.overlay 4.11.0.qualifier to bundle org.apache.axis 1.4.0.;
...
...
...
 No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
[INFO] {osgi.os=win32, osgi.ws=win32, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.eclipse.birt.designer 4.11.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.birt.designer 4.11.0.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]
[ERROR] See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
[ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.birt:org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite:4.11.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\dev\git\birt\build\org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite\pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.birt:org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite:4.11.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\dev\git\birt\build\org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite\pom.xml
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.artifacts.DependencyResolutionException: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.birt:org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite:4.11.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\dev\git\birt\build\org.eclipse.birt.p2updatesite\pom.xml
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.doResolveDependencies (P2DependencyResolver.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies (P2DependencyResolver.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject (DefaultTychoResolver.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ResolverException: See log for details
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve (ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve (AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.doResolveDependencies (P2DependencyResolver.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies (P2DependencyResolver.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject (DefaultTychoResolver.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException
```

Has anyone been able to build the latest BIRT source from scratch? I don't know if its been noticed by anyone?

P.S: I started building with clean slate i.e nothing in .m2 and .p2 folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/flugtiger/birt instead.
At least when I tried to build BIRT a few months ago this worked.

Please note that this is not the official BIRT build.